# Can an IV laser cause eye damaged when used intraorally?

Tags: lasers, medical-devices

Here are the specs for the laser https://summuslaser.com/lasers/lasers-horizon-medical/
It has a dental attachment.
When used intraorally and the tip is pointed to the roof of the mouth, I can see the bright red light in both eyes - almost like staring at the sun with eyelids closed. Even though the eyes are closed, I wear eyewear protection provided by the doctor and a towel on top. The laser just penetrates through the roof of the mouth and makes the light visible to me. Now, I know that you are not supposed to look at the laser directly and as described above I did not.

I asked the doctor about it, and they said that it is fine.

However, I had blurry vision after the procedure (that was dental procedure) and sore / irritated eyes.

Is it possible to cause damage to the eyes by using this laser as describe above?

If it is not a correct forum for this question, please advise where would be the better place to post.
Thank you for your input!

Update:
I say it is class IV as it says so on the website "Class IV laser therapy is a drug-free solution that is proven to be 90% effective at treating the symptoms of neuropathy." I was treated with "neuralgia" setting for 4 times. The doctor explained that this setting goes "deeper".

Comment: why are you asking some strangers on the internet ... ask SUMMUS

Comment: @jstola summus contact us form is not working. I will call them. It never hurts to ask strangers as those strangers could be professional in the field that are not selling the product and as such would say that it is "fine." But yes I will call them as well.

Comment: I don't have an answer. I was just curious is all. I had similar wonderings (not wonderings in my case, I'm positive it's not good for your hearing) about two jaw surgeries I had where I know they took drills and saws to the jaw bone which must have been very very loud and not good for hearing through direct bone conduction. Of course, I could not be conscious for it and I fount scant research concerning it.